# Navigation Drawer Activity con un Fragment que tiene un Button que trae datos de un servidor

Tags: android, android-studio, json, android-fragment, android-intent

Creé un proyecto de tipo **Navigation Drawer Activity** como verán en la imagen de abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde las secciones **Import - Gallery, etc** las trato a cada una como un **fragment**

Como verán en la imagen de arriba al hacer clic en **Import** en este caso llamamos a un **fragment** el cual contiene un **Button** llamado Actualizar.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando le doy clic en el botón actualizar, me traiga un archivo php que tengo en un servidor.

Los datos los logro traer correctamente en un activity como verán en la imagen de arriba, pero en un fragment no sé como hacerlo, no lo he logrado realizar.

Aca pueden ver que es lo que quiero traer cuando hago clic en Import que vendría a ser un fragment.

Lo ideal seria que no esté el botón "Actualizar", que solo al ingresar al import traiga esa lista que se encuentra en un archivo .php en un servidor.

### Este es mi archivo JSON

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";


    public JSONParser() {

    }

      public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List params) {
        try {

           if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

          try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

---

Mi MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
          fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,new FragmentImport()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Alquileres para comunicarme al servidor

```
public class alquileres extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empresaList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_empresas = "http://deltaintegralelectromecanica.com/arcan.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "empresas";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NOMBRE = "nombre";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    ListView lista;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alquilerese);

        // Hashmap para el ListView
        empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAllProducts);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }//fin onCreate


    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Antes de empezar el background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(alquileres.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Cargando comercios. Por favor espere...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * obteniendo todos los productos
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_empresas, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    //Log.i("ramiro", "produtos.length" + products.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NOMBRE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap map = new HashMap();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NOMBRE, name);

                        empresaList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            alquileres.this,
                            empresaList,
                            R.layout.single_post,
                            new String[] {
                                    TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NOMBRE,
                            },
                            new int[] {
                                    R.id.single_post_tv_id,
                                    R.id.single_post_tv_nombre,
                            });
                    // updating listview
                    //setListAdapter(adapter);
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

Y el fragment

```
public class FragmentImport extends Fragment {

    private Button btn;



    public FragmentImport() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_import, container, false);

        btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ListSong = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),alquileres.class);
                startActivity(ListSong);
            }
        });

        return view;


}
}
```

---

Al hacer clic en el botón actualizar del fragment, la aplicación se detiene.

Comment: ese no es un archivo json, es una clase que utilizas para eniar y recibir un JSON.
Cuando dices archivo JSON, se espera una estructura asi {"codigo_respuesta":"01", "mensaje_respuesta":"Exito", "nombre_sujeto": "Pepa la cerdita"}

Comment: Si eso perdon me confundi, es la clase que utilizo para enviar y recibir

Comment: creo que es menos complicado usando Volley y RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Usa lo mismo pero en el `onActivityCreated` dentro de tu `fragment`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Hashmap para el ListView
          empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread
           new LoadAllProducts().execute();
           lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAllProducts);

           ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
           actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no logro acertar, esto lo coloco debajo del oneCreateView de mi fragment pero cuando agreso eso hay ciertas cosas como el LoadAllProducts que pertenece a un metodo que se encuntra en Alquielres aparece en rojo como el getSupportActionBar.

Comment: Alguien mas que quiera ayudar?